# How to maintain a NodeJS server application after closing SSH terminal

Tags: node.js, ssh, terminal, digital-ocean, nodemon

I created a Digital Ocean Droplet where I cloned my NodeJS application from Git and the `npm install` all dependencies. When I SSH into the terminal and Run `nodemon init` command to launch the server application, it does just that and I can access it via my domain just fine. The problem though is once I close the Putty SSH terminal, the site is no longer available. I have tested this multiple times and it seems the problem is indeed closing the Terminal. So how can I solve this problem and make sure that my server app is still running even after I close the SSH connection to my droplet.

Comment: See “nohup”, perhaps. The program has to be detached from the terminal/session - the command used likely does not daemon itself suitably. This may also indicate using an unsuitable method to run the server..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install pm2 globally instead of nodemon then run your app with this command:

```
pm2 start app.js
```